# Using Amazon's RDS Read Replica

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm interested in the potential read performance increase of having a "Read replica" of my amazon RDS. Before I try, I'd like to be clearer on a few things.

1. After creating a read replica, how does this effect my app? Do the benefits happen behind the scenes at aws or do I need to write logic for my application to know that it can read from this new replica instance?
2. It mentions a "Brief I/O interruption" that can last up to a minute [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html) Does that mean my production app is 'dead in the water' for up to a minute? Has anyone experienced anything longer than that?
3. Any other risk I should be aware of?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After creating a read replica, how does this effect my app? Do the benefits happen behind the scenes at aws or do I need to write logic for my application to know that it can read from this new replica instance?

You need to modify your application to send some or all of your SQL `SELECT` queries to the new replica.

> It mentions a "Brief I/O interruption" that can last up to a minute here Does that mean my production app is 'dead in the water' for up to a minute? Has anyone experienced anything longer than that?

I haven't seen longer than a minute. If you're running a multi-AZ RDS, you won't have this happen.

Comment: Thanks - surprisingly not obvious in the official documentation

Comment: @contool Yeah, the AWS docs suffer a bit from being so extensive and detailed - it can be hard to find answers to specific questions. I strongly recommend the AWS basic support - some of the best $50/month I spend, and you can turn it on just for a month at a time to get some answers.